# Extbase DatabaseQueryProcessor should respect sorting

Tags: typoscript, extbase

How to get DatabaseQueryProcessor to sort records as like as they are ordered in backend field (stored comma seperated list of field "pages"?

```
10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
10 {
    table = pages
    pidInList = 1
    recursive = 99
    where {
        data = field:pages
        wrap = nav_hide=0 AND uid IN (|)
    }
    as = pages
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below untested sample:

```
10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
10 {
    table = pages
    pidInList = 1
    recursive = 99

    where = TEXT
    where {
        data = field:pages
        wrap = nav_hide=0 AND uid IN (|)
    }

    order = TEXT
    order.stdWrap {
        field = pages

        split {
            token = ,
            cObjNum = 1|*|2

            1.current = 1
            1.trim = 1
            1.noTrimWrap = |uid=||

            2.current = 1
            2.trim = 1
            2.noTrimWrap = |, uid=||
        }
    }

    as = pages
}
```

Basically I creates the following `order by` statment (Lets use `1,2,3`as uid samples):

```
Order By uid=1, uid=2, uid=3
```

I use the [splite](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/TypoScriptFunctions/Split/Index.html) typoscript function to spit the uid list by comma and then `cObjNum` to wrap the first item with configuration `1` and the rest with configuration `2`. `cObjNum` is not documented very well but you can take a look at the source code unit tests to get a idea of the format: [\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\Unit\Service\TypoScriptServiceTest::explodeConfigurationForOptionSplitProvider](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7/typo3/sysext/core/Tests/Unit/TypoScript/TypoScriptServiceTest.php#L298)